# Android - Getting null descriptors from a Characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to interface with an Red Bear Labs nRF8001 Arduino Shield via Android Studio. I am succesfully able to send a command via Android and recieve it on my Arduino.

However I wish to read the response from my Arduino, using "OnCharacteristicChange" - however research showed a descriptor is required.

This is my code sample:

```
  @Override
         public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
             super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
             if(status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                 Log.i("BtServiceCallback","OnServicesDiscovered Failed!");
             }
             BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE);
             BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_TX);

             BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(RBLGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
             descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
             gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

             byte[] val = readSetPoint.getBytes();
             characteristic.setValue(val);
             gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,true);
             gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

             Log.i("Sent = ", characteristic.getStringValue(0));
         }
```

Whenever I try to create a descriptor from the characteristic, I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor.setValue(byte[])' on a null object reference
    at uk.ac.as988brighton.bluecontroller.MainActivity$1.onServicesDiscovered(MainActivity.java:160)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:286)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:103)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

I am using the UUIDs from RBL's [Github](https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android/blob/master/Examples/Android%20Studio%20Examples/Chat/src/com/redbear/chat/RBLGattAttributes.java#L27):

```
public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String BLE_SHIELD_TX = "713d0003-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e";
public static String BLE_SHIELD_RX = "713d0002-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e";
public static String BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE = "713d0000-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e";
```

I am unsure as to what is causing the null descriptor.

**Edit**
I have used different combinations for the descriptor - such as using

```
 BluetoothGattDescriptor characteristic.getDescriptor(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_TX);
```

But still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make sure you're naming things the same. Both your service and characteristic uuid are declared as `BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE` and `BLE_SHIELD_TX` but you're trying to access them with `UUID_BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE` and `UUID_BLE_SHIELD_TX`.

So change 
`BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE);` to

`BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(RBLService.BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE);`

and

`BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_TX);` to

`BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(RBLService.BLE_SHIELD_TX);`

and I believe it should work. Also make sure you are broadcasting those exact service and characteristic uuid's from your peripheral.

Good luck!